# Exporting FBX mesh with armature and pose

Tags: mesh, rigging, export, bones, .fbx

I am fairly new to the use of rigging in Blender. I created this small robot to which I applied a pose and armature, however when **exporting** to **FBX** something seems to happen to the proportions (the end goal would be to **import it to Unreal Engine**), the mesh warps, showing only the legs of the robot, trying to export just the mesh, no problem occurred so I assume the error is within the armature, does anyone have any ideas?

**Thanks in advance! :D**

Here are the photos:

[image: Robot in Blender]

[image: Exported FBX]

Comment: Please share your blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there. Also, did you apply the Scale (Ctrl-A > Scale) to both model and armature before exporting it?

Comment: Please add a simple exaple file showcasing your problem.